# Core Data Fetch Results Reduced Set of Related Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have a NSFetchResult that returns managed objects that contain MANY related objects ( Aobj ->> Bobj). The "Bobj" managed object contains a BOOL attribute "isSet" (stored as NSNumber). The NSFetchResult returns all Aobj objects.

I would like a suggestion for an NSPredicate that would return an Aobj with only those Bojs where isSet is TRUE (@1).

Currently, I enumerate over my NSArray of Aobjs returned by my fetch result so that I can get my filtered NSArray of Aobjs this way:

```
- (NSArray *)filteredObject:(Aobj *)aObj
{
    NSMutableArray* bObjs  = [aObj.bObjs mutableCopy];

    [bObjs enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(Bobj* bObj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         if (bObj.isSet == [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO])
         {
             [bObjs removeObject:story];
         }
     }];
    return bObjs;
}
```

Asked another way: how would I define an NSPredicate for my NSFetchResult that would get all my Aobjs but limit the related Bobjs to those matching Bobj.isSet == YES?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.bObjs.isSet == YES"];
[myFetchRequest setPredicate:myPredicate];
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:myFetchRequest error:&error];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution produces an "uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'" error.

Comment: We can try fetching all data from core data and then using NSPredicate. Replace filteredObject: method in your code, try NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.isSet == YES"]; return [aObj.bOBjs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];

Comment: Thanks Chinmaya! That second predicate did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery. Subqueries follow this general format:

`SUBQUERY(relationship, related_thing, predicate)`

`relationship` is the relationship on the object being evaluated.
`related_thing` is an individual object in the relationship. It's prefixed by a $ and is then used in the predicate (not shown above, for clarity).
`predicate` is the predicate to apply to `related_thing`.

With your example, it would look like (assuming your relationship is called 'bobjs'):

`SUBQUERY(bobjs, $obj, $obj.isSet == YES)`

Subqueries can be quite powerful. For example, you can also apply collection operators to the subquery:

`SUBQUERY(bobjs, $obj, $obj.isSet == YES).@count > 1` would give you each AObj that has at least one object in the 'bobjs' relationship with isSet equal to YES. Obviously, you can use other collections operators or layer logical operations or additional expressions on top of this.

Comment: Hi Quellish. I should have mentioned that I tried both alternatives. The first gives me an error that the predicate cannot be parsed. The second result, as you say, simply returns AObjs that have at least one Bobj that is so marked, but it still returns all the Bobjs related to the AObj. That is, if an instance of AObj has 10 related Bobjs, and only 4 of those Bobjs are marked .isSet = YES, then I'd like the Aobj returned with only those 4 Bobjs included in the NSSet.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here: "then I'd like the Aobj returned with only those 4 Bobjs included in the NSSet." You want the relationship on Aobj to ONLY contain objects that have obj.isSet == YES? That you can't do in the query, you can do it in Aobj's implementation.

Comment: Here is the error produced by the first alternative: uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(Bojs, $x, $x.isSet == %@)"'. (Happens whether or not isSet == %@, @1, YES, or @YES.)